# Хеш файла Java/JS

Tags: javascript, java-ee, хеширование

Подскажите. Мне нужно сделать проверку целостности файлов, которые я буду отправлять клиенту (JavaEE) - файлы JS, к примеру. Когда будет происходить какой либо запрос от клиента к серверу то будет браться хеш файлов js на стороне клиента и передаваться в запросе. Как мне получить на стороне сервера хеш отдаваемого файла и как его получить при помощи JS на стороне клиента?

Comment: https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA - имплементация sha хешей на javascript. И я таки не понял, что у вас клиент? java апплет? jsp? чисто js?

Comment: Еще есть такая штука, но browser support оч маленький: http://caniuse.com/#search=integrity

Comment: @ru_volt Клиент - JSP(+ HTML) + JS + CSS
Сервер - JSP + Servlet + Filters + MySql

Comment: Бесполезно же...

Comment: @Qwertiy бесполезно что?

Comment: @Tsyklop, если кто-то может подменить отправляемый файл, то он и код проверки может подменить. Следовательно, проверка бесполезна.

Comment: @Qwertiy а сервер просто так существует? на сервере тоже будет проверка... Если файл другой...или он будет изменён но Хеш изменится тоже... На сервере будет хранится шаблон Хеша которому должен соответствовать пришедший.

Comment: @Tsyklop, вопрос: "и как его получить при помощи JS на стороне клиента". Если код подменён, то что мешает с клиента отправить оригинальный хэш, просто заменив кусок кода с хэшированием на оправку конкретного значения?

Comment: @Qwertiy помимо это будут отправляться данные которые индентифицируют клиента.